# Translate MYSQL to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so i tried to convert a little bit of MYSQL to the new PDO;

```
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='un'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
if($check == 0){
echo "Do this";
}
```

How i did it in PDO:

```
$u_check = $databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE :username = '$un'");

$check =  $databaseConnection->query($u_check);
if($check == 0){
echo "do stuff"
}
```

But as expeced i get an error:

> Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 27

Line 27:    `$check =  $databaseConnection->query($u_check);`

I have no idea how to get the same result in PDO

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT 1:

I have this now:

```
if($reg) {
  if($em==$em2){
    $u_check = $databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE :username = '$un'");
    $u_check->bind_param("s", "un");
    $result = $u_check->execute();
      if($result){
          echo "hoi";
        }
      }
    }
```

gives me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 26

EDIT 2: my code at the moment;

```
<?php include("inc/header.inc.php");?>
<?php
$reg = $_POST['reg'];

$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$un = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswd = "";
$pswd2 = "";
$d = "";

$fn = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags($_POST['uname']);
$em = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags($_POST['password2']);
$d = date("d-m-Y");

if($reg) {
  if($em==$em2){
    $u_check = $databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username");
    $u_check->bindParam(':username', $un);//un is the given username that user types
    $u_check->execute();
    $check = $u_check->rowCount();
        if($check > 0){
            if($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2){
              if($pswd==$pswd2){
                if(strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25){
                  echo "Maximum characters is 25!";
                }else{
                  if(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){
                    echo "Your pass must be between 5 and 30 characters!";
                  }else{
                    $pswd = md5($pswd);
                    $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                    $query = $databaseConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, email, password, sign_up_date, activated) VALUES (:un, :fn, :ln, :em, :pswd, :d, '0')");
                    $query->execute();
                    die("<h2>Welcome to Profiles</h2>Login to your account to get started...");
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }else{
            echo "Already exists!";
          }
        }
      }
?>
```

So, now i get the message "Already exists!" everytime,

Altho the setup itself does not work, its not putting the stuff from the form in ....

EDIT 3

I get this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\SocialMedia\first\index.php on line 50 which is line

```
if($pswd!=$pswd2){
    $errors[] .= 'Passwords are not the same';
  }elseif(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){
    $errors[] .='Your pass must be between 5 and 30 characters!'
  }else{
    $pswd_md = md5($pswd);
  }
```

which is this line:

```
}else{
```

Comment: uh.. so you are supposed to bind these variables for the prepared string...

Comment: Yeah Look at my EDIT 2

Comment: Dump the user param after your execute to see what the usernames are: $u_check->debugDumpParams(); if they are really are in the database then..

Comment: There R plenty of clear tuts on this out there like [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/). Whats the exact reaon u do not use google to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong...Try this one:

```
<?php include("inc/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?php

function display_errors($errors){
    $display = '<ul>';
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        $display .= '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
    }
    $display .= '</ul>';
    return $display;
}

$reg = $_POST['reg'];

$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$un = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswd = "";
$pswd2 = "";
$d = "";

if(isset($reg)) {
  $errors = array();
  $fn = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
  $ln = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
  $un = strip_tags($_POST['uname']);
  $em = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
  $em2 = strip_tags($_POST['email2']);
  $pswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
  $pswd2 = strip_tags($_POST['password2']);
  $d = date("d-m-Y");
  $required = array('fname','lname','uname','email','email2','password','password2');

  foreach($required as $field){
    if($_POST[$field] == ''){
      $errors[] .= $field. ' is required';
    }
  }

  if(strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25){
    $errors[] .= "Maximum characters is 25!";
  }

  if($pswd!=$pswd2){
    $errors[] .= 'Passwords are not the same';
  }elseif(strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5){
    $errors[] .='Your pass must be between 5 and 30 characters!'
  }else{
    $pswd_md = md5($pswd);
  }


  if($em != $em2){
    $errors[] .= 'Emails are not the same';
  }

    $u_check = $databaseConnection->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= :username");
    $u_check->bindParam(':username', $un);//un is the given username that user types
    $u_check->execute();
    $check = $u_check->rowCount();

    if($check > 0){
      $errors[] .= 'User Exists. Choose another username';
    }

    if(!empty($errors)){
      echo display_errors($errors);
    }else{
      $ac = 0;
      $query = $databaseConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, email, password, sign_up_date, activated) VALUES (:un, :fn, :ln, :em, :pswd, :d, :ac)");
      $query->bindParam(':un',$un);
      $query->bindParam(':fn',$fn);
      $query->bindParam(':ln',$ln);
      $query->bindParam(':em',$em);
      $query->bindParam(':pswd',$pswd_md);
      $query->bindParam(':d',$d);
      $query->bindParam(':ac',$ac);
      $query->execute();
    }
    if($query){
      //INSERT SUCCESS
      echo 'Success';
    }else{
      echo 'Failed;'
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: This will work! Let me try this in my complete code!

Comment: i forgot semicolon after 'Your pass must be....' ;

Comment: just fill in the semicolon in the end of the line 49..

Comment: You are awesome! It does work :D Only one small problem, it is not inserting the DATE into the database, it shows me 0000-00-00

I need the date to be DAY-MONTH-YEAR

Comment: You have to change the line 33 to $d = date(Y-m-d); If you want to change the format when you echo this date then you have to change it as you want(day-month-year). The date in database must be Y-m-d formated. ;)

Comment: Aaah alright, thanks for the big help!

Comment: In the future, don't answer with a code dump and say "Try this". Add value by explaining at least something.

Answer (score 0):

It is because for **query()** you need a String, but you give an object (Look: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php)

There is an example:

```
<?php
function getFruit($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

If you want to use prepare have a look at: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php

You have to use $var->execute(array($var1, $var2));

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly you want to check if the given username exists in the database. Call ->execute() on the prepared statement and use rowCount() on the returned object to get the number of results.

Check the documentation for more info: [PDO rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) and [PDO Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

But if you really only need the number of rows where the username is the given username (since you select username and use it in the condition also) you can simply select the number:

```
SELECT count(username) FROM users GROUP BY username HAVING username = $username
```